# Transparent proxy for testing server responses offline in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, okhttp, e2e-testing

I have a data-driven Android app scaffold. Adding tests, aiming for 100% coverage. Using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp).

**How do I transparently intercept calls to my server with mock responses?**

Want this for—end-to-end as well as—unit tests. E.g.: setting build-type to `MockServer` should load an app that will show mock responses in the emulator.

Comment: Hmm, [mock-server](http://www.mock-server.com) might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: The closest I found was [`angular/in-memory-web-api`](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) in the web world (TypeScript/JavaScript, Angular 2). Its examples are lacking, would be good to know if it supports full CRUD across HTTP verbs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into okhttp [mockwebserver](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)?

I use it for mocking responses and verifying/showing requests.

If you want to use this with a build type, you can generate an Android resource or java constant in gradle and then start the server and set the path accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to go far enough. It's only useful for unit testing, not for e2e and live-app [without backend] testing.

Answer (score 0):

For a unit tests, you should be able to write your code in such a way as to isolate the usage of OkHttp. In doing this, you can mock out the client (using something like [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/)) and have it behave however you want. After all, in a unit test we only want to test a single piece of code, not any of it's dependencies.

Something like this in Java. Likewise, the pattern works elsewhere (like Javascript)

```
public class ClassUnderTest {

    private final OkHttpClient client;

    public ClassUnderTest(OkHttpClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    // Other code...
}

// In your tests
OkHttpClient mockClient = mock(OkHttpClient.class);
when(mockClient.newCall(any(Request.class)).thenThrow(...);
ClassUnderTest testClass = new ClassUnderTest(mockClient);

verify(mockClient).doSomething();
```

For integration tests, mockwebserver looks to be your best bet (as others have mentioned).

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to go far enough. It's only useful for unit testing, not for e2e and live-app [without backend] testing.